# What is the cause of Unhandled Exception: System.ArgumentException: key doesn't exist: sonaranalyzer-cs.analyzerId?

Tags: sonarqube

Running version 2.0.24 of the MSBuild Scanner from the command line produces the error below.

The same analysis was successful with version 2.0 and the documentation does not describe this key - either as a mandatory or extension.

The exception is thrown by the scanner and the mandatory params are passed on the commandline including version, key and name.

Projects were built using MSBuild 14.0 and SonarQube version 5.6 LTS is used with version 5.1 of the C# plugin.  The version matrix states that this version of the MSBuild Scanner supports 4.5 or above.  There is no VB plugin installed as no projects consist of VB code.

```
[1] - Unhandled Exception: System.ArgumentException: key doesn't exist: sonaranalyzer-cs.analyzerId  
[2] - at SonarQube.TeamBuild.PreProcessor.Roslyn.Model.RoslynRuleSetGenerator.mandatoryPropertyValue(String propertyKey)  
[3] - at SonarQube.TeamBuild.PreProcessor.Roslyn.Model.RoslynRuleSetGenerator.generate(IEnumerable 1 activeRules, IEnumerable 1 inactiveRules, String language)  
[4] - at SonarQube.TeamBuild.PreProcessor.Roslyn.RoslynAnalyzerProvider.ConfigureAnalyzer(String language, IEnumerable 1 activeRules, IEnumerable 1 inactiveRules)  
[5]
- at SonarQube.TeamBuild.PreProcessor.Roslyn.RoslynAnalyzerProvider.SetupAnalyzer (TeamBuildSettings settings, IDictionary 2 serverSettings, IEnumerable 1 activeRules, IEnumerable 1 inactiveRules, String language)  
[6] - at SonarQube.TeamBuild.PreProcessor.TeamBuildPreProcessor.FetchArgumentsAndRulesets(ISonarQubeServer server, ProcessedArgs args, TeamBuildSettings settings, IDictionary 2& serverSettings, List 1& analyzersSettings)  
[7] - at SonarQube.TeamBuild.PreProcessor.TeamBuildPreProcessor.DoExecute(ProcessedArgs args)  
[8] - at SonarQube.TeamBuild.PreProcessor.TeamBuildPreProcessor.Execute(String[] args)  
[9] - at SonarQube.Bootstrapper.BootstrapperClass.PreProcess()  
[10] - at SonarQube.Bootstrapper.BootstrapperClass.Execute() 
[11] - at SonarQube.Bootstrapper.Program.Main(String[] args) 
[12] - at SonarQube.Old.Bootstrapper.Program.Main(String[] args)
```

Many thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: This is a lazy question, why no add more description

Comment: Fair comment.  Updated now with more detail.

Comment: Can you share a the list of plugins installed in Sonarqube. I have got a similar error. Unhandled Exception: System.ArgumentException: key doesn't exist. Remove vbdotnet plugin and it works.

Comment: I am seeing this exact same exception. Did you ever find an answer? This is the only post I have found related to this exception.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, I think I might have the answer. I believe the issue is that they added this new sonaranalyzer-cs.analyzerId key in the latest version. If I am right, you are like me and are running an older version of the sonarqube server, but you downloaded the latest version of the scanner. So the older version of the server does not send the key, and the newer version of the scanner requires it as a mandatory server setting.

When I switch to using the version of the scanner that came with the server it all works as expected. I believe I could also upgrade our server, but that is not on the road map at the time.